# Change the value of a column in previous row and the current row whenever a new row is inserted in PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, plsql, plsqldeveloper, dbms-output

lets say the table name is **abc** and **columns are **name varchar(20)** and **status varchar(1)**,****status** can be **either 'y' or 'n'** on insertion of each new row the **status value of the new row must be set to 'y' and the status value of previous row has to be set to 'n'.** Please guide me with a solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pl/sql, you can fire a pre update statement.
So before loading into the table, issue this

```
sql_stmnt= 'UPDATE table SET status=''n'' WHERE status =''y''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmnt;
commit;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO...'
```

Comment: The approach @KoushikRoy outlines is valid but a couple comments. First, **do not commit after the update. Apparently your table must have exactly 1 row with status 'y', so what happens when an error occurs during the Insert. Your database is now corrupted as there is no 'Y' status. This is a basic transaction and both statements need to succeed or neither is committed. Second, there seems no reason for dynamic SQL. Always prefer static SQL if it is available.